# why I have to make empty function in react context object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand reacjs context API from docs. In the provided example on [Updating Context from a Nested Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)  I found they created a context object like that :

```
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: themes.dark,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});
```

So I asked what is the role of `toggleTheme: () => {}`. I found two live example for this snippet of code, They both using the same expression of empty function/method . I tried to remove it at all to see where it affect ... and I found nothing. Every thing working good, that makes me curious to know what it doing?

- **first** Live sinppet : https://codesandbox.io/s/73jkjq57lq
- **second** Live sinppet : https://codesandbox.io/s/p9p4jmqkq7

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance one can understand that in this context you can change a theme. As it is provided in the context object.

This is a method you are providing in the context:

```
toggleTheme: () => {},
```

if you need to change the theme, then you know that context is providing you one method named `toggleTheme` and as it is a method you can trigger it on the basis of your particular event such as `mouseevents, keyboardevents` or `redux actions` if it is implemented there.

Comment: sorry if I'm stupid, you said *"that context is providing"* but actually in the two example above the method passed from App component or the parent what ever the name is? and no relation between  `toggleTheme` in context obj and `toggleTheme` the method created in parent component that's makes me to remove `toggleTheme` from context obj and the code nothing affect.also you said "I can trigger it in events .."  what makes me interesting to trigger empty function ?

Comment: plz.. if possible to edit one of the two example above and make a practical example this will be great to understand your point ...thanks

Comment: @AymanMorsy your first comment's question. That is just a signature for the method, if required do the logic in the `toggleTheme` method

Comment: Or you can say it defaults to context's object if consumer doesn't have it

Comment: plz forgive me English is not my mother tongue and Javascript my first lang ... what I learned right now when I create default value. it takes the place of  real value in absence  so I tried to console log "hello" from context obj method and on the other side I removed the initialization of  `toggleTheme`
 from component , I expected to run as a fallback it looks nothing match