# What really should you pass into createContect()?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, createcontext

I see all of the following forms:

1. `createContext()`
2. `createContext(null)`
3. `createContext({})`
4. `createContext(theme: 'light', toggleTheme: () => {})`

[example of #4 is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375282/why-i-have-to-make-empty-function-in-react-context-object).  So can you just use #1 or #2 above and they are the same as #3 or #4?

#4 above seem like it has an empty function that somehow miraculously becomes something else? (because empty function. is not useful and supposedly it should do something). I sometimes see a

```js
createContext(isFooBar: false, setIsFooBar: () => {})
```

as if somehow the `setIsFooBar()` will become a function that can alter the flag `isFooBar`. How does it really work?

Comment: That value is the default value. Ie, it's the value that will be provided if you forget to render a `<MyContext.Provider>` (or deliberately don't render it). What the default value should be is up to your use case; we can't answer it for you.

Comment: Within a component, `useContext(MyContext)` will return the value of the nearest `MyContext.Provider` that contains the component. The `value` passed to `createContext(value)` is the default value returned if the component is not within any `MyContent.Provider`. There are many articles discussing contexts, but the [official React documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) is a good start.

Comment: @NicholasTower my goodness, we can actually skip `<MyContext.Provider>` ? Is it in the docs?  I thought we always have to have that by reading the docs, or else the behavior is "undefined" and if it works, there really is no guarantee

Comment: `my goodness, we can actually skip <MyContext.Provider> ?` It's supported, but rarely useful. 99% of the time you want a provider, since that's the only way to have a changing value